Do all >1D box fractals really have lines in them?
Consider an $n \times n$ square split up into $n^2$ cells the natural way. Now suppose we fill in $1 \le k \le n^2$ of these cells s.t. $\log_n(k) > 1$. Is it always the case that there will be a filled in line segment of length $n$ in this set?
Intuitively this problem arises from making fractals. We notice that if we make a box fractal by recursively applying some $k$ out of the $n^2$ cells the Hausdorff Dimension of this is always $\log_n(k)$. When $\log_n(k) > 1$ these fractals always seem to have a line segment in them for the examples I have explored. An example is here if you want to see that visually.

No! There are many counter examples.
Basically consider any $n$ queens solution and then put one extra square. Since there are AT MOST $2$ cells in a particular row, column, or diagonal we can't possibly have a line segment of length greater than $2\sqrt{2}$ in the set. This is considerably smaller than $n$ for large $n$.
